# Can't execute python script server-side inside php shell_exec

Tags: python, php, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite, shell-exec

I got a strange situation and i can't figure out what's the problem.

I want to use **ajax** to make a request on the server (Raspberry Pi 3) that use **php**.

The php script handle the request, run a **python script** with **shell_exec** and return the result of the shell_exec to the client.
The python script execute a prediction of **Tensorflow Lite model** and print the result.

The problem is that my shell_exec() is not executed and the php return a response with status 200 and response = 0.

I thought it was some timeout on server because python script need 10 seconds to print a result, but changing python code to only a "sleep(180)" make the ajax request waiting for 3 minutes.

Change the python script back.

So, I think it's some about the python script.

Running

> php server.php

on raspberry I got the output of the python script as I exepct.

So, maybe it's something about apache user who run php script (www-data, etc...). I changed permission of all files to 777 but the error still persist.

***ajax.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>

<title>Ajax Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script>
function reply() {
    $.ajax({
          url: 'risposta.php',
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          async: true,
          timeout: 0,
          success: function(response){
             if(response != 0){
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response;
             }else{
                alert('Error');
             }
          },
       });

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="formesempio">
<input type="text" id="nome">
<input type="button" value="Play" onclick="javascript:reply()">
</form>
<p>Result: <span id="result"></span></p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***server.php***

```
<?php
$command = "python3 /var/www/html/DBR/predict.py --fn /var/www/html/img.jpg";
$out = shell_exec($command);
echo $out;
?>
```

***predict.py***

```
from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import time
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from DBR_utils import print_human_readable_dog_deploy, get_dog_from_predictions


# Variabili globali
model_path = "DBR/DBR.tflite"
label_path = "DBR/IT_breeds.txt"






def set_input_tensor(interpreter, image):
  tensor_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['index']
  input_tensor = interpreter.tensor(tensor_index)()[0]
  input_tensor[:, :] = image

def classify_image(interpreter, image, top_k=1):
  set_input_tensor(interpreter, image)

  interpreter.invoke()
  output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]
  output = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details['index'])
  return output



# -- Parser --
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='DBR')
parser.add_argument('--fn', type=str, required=True, help='filename')
args = parser.parse_args()


interpreter = Interpreter(model_path)
#print("Model Loaded Successfully.")

interpreter.allocate_tensors()
_, height, width, _ = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['shape']
#print("Image Shape (", width, ",", height, ")")

# Load an image to be classified.
image = Image.open(args.fn).convert('RGB').resize((width, height))

# Classify the image.
time1 = time.time()
output = classify_image(interpreter, image)
time2 = time.time()
classification_time = np.round(time2-time1, 3)
#print("Classificaiton Time =", classification_time, "seconds.")

labels = []
with open(label_path, 'r') as f:
    tmp = f.readlines()
    for l in tmp:
        labels.append(l.rstrip())

labels = pd.Series(labels)
dog = get_dog_from_predictions(np.squeeze(output), labels, args.fn)
res = print_human_readable_dog_deploy(dog)
print(res)
```

Comment: try to execute "python3 --version" (inside php) to know if it return result. Another thing to try is the complete path to executable python like /usr/bin/python3 or wherever it is.

Comment: In your ajax code why you are posting data to risposta.php file while your php file is server.php

Comment: Thanks to all guys!
I forget renaming in ajax code to post on stack overflow only.

Comment: Good news, I solved! Something in python script was making bad response.
Also import pandas as pd was making bad response... little changes and everything works now.

Comment: Hi @DanieleMenchetti, Glad to hear that the issue is solved! If you have time, would it be possible to post your findings of how your issue was solved as an answer to your question here?

Comment: Hi, I found that the "shell_exec" command above got some problems when in the predict.py there's "import pandas as pd". So I remove this line and everything about pandas and now everything works.
Unfortunately I don't know why...
Have a nice day! :)